# Rails Rabl gem not showing line numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

Whenever the rendering in rabl templates fails, it just shows the error. It does not show the line numbers. Has anyone faced this issue yet?

**Example trace**:

```
Rendered campaigns/show.json.rabl (1377.9ms)  
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass  
(eval):21:in `block (2 levels) in render'  
/Users/pkhadloya/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/myapp/gems/rabl-0.8.5/lib/rabl/builder.rb:87:in `call'  
/Users/pkhadloya/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/myapp/gems/rabl-0.8.5/lib/rabl/builder.rb:87:in `node'
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this helpful link: http://davidsommers.com/2012/07/28/use-the-debugger-not-puts.html
It shows how to debug in rabl. But line numbers would have been more beneficial.